# I can't see ${message} in my first spring mvc example

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc, controller

I have read [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/06/spring-3-mvc-create-hello-world-application-spring-3-mvc.html) tutorial to write my hello world application with spring mvc.But I cant see ${message} in hello.jsp when I click on "Say Hello" link in index.jsp. My code actually is same with code in tutorial. I am new in Spring and I can't find where I did mistake please help me.

HelloWorldController.java

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>springmvcben</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
This is message:
 ${message}
</body>
</html>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="hello.jsp">Say Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This my project structure:
[image]

And this is my output

```
?ub 09, 2012 1:37:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\windows live;c:\program files\nvidia corporation\physx\common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\wbem;C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\100\tools\binn\;c:\program files\microsoft sql server\100\dts\binn\;c:\program files\windows live\shared;c:\program files\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\db2\BIN;C:\db2\FUNCTION;C:\db2\SAMPLES\REPL;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Users\Ferid\Desktop\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-win32\eclipse;;. ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:22 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:springmvcben' did not find a matching property. ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:22 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:22 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization processed in 520 ms ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting service Catalina ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.25 ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext checkUnusualURLPattern INFO: Suspicious url pattern: "*.*" in context [/springmvcben] - see section SRV.11.2 of the Servlet specification log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring' ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.25-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\MerhabaDunya.war ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.25-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\docs ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.25-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\examples ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized() ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized() ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@1be0de') ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.25-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\host-manager ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.25-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\manager ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.25-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\ROOT ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] ?ub 09, 2012 1:37:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in 6007 ms
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: What *do* you see? Also, you're using both 2.5 and 3.0 in your web.xml; decide which.

Comment: @DaveNewton when I open hello.jsp I see only "This is message:"

Comment: @DaveNewton you said that "you're using both 2.5 and 3.0 in your web.xml" I can't understand it actually I am new in spring.

Comment: Look at your web.xml; web-app_2_5.xsd then web-app_3_0.xsd.

Comment: I changed both of these to 3.0 @DaveNewton

Comment: I guess that my application doesn't use controller.

Comment: I'll test in a little bit; I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be mistaken, but the `DispatcherServlet` mapping is pointing elsewhere - it is in fact mapped to *.html, while you are requesting hello.jsp - this skips the dispatcher servlet and goes straight to the JSP page. In addition, your JstlView is configured to fetch JSPs from the WEB-INF folder.

Try moving `hello.jsp` in the `WEB-INF` folder and then invoking `/hello.html` instead.

Comment: @faridmovsumov Oh, yeah, you shouldn't be accessing hello.jsp directly, but by going through the dispatch servlet. I assumed you were making the correct request--Alessandro is correct about that. The JstlView mapping itself is fine, however; as long as the JSPs are where they're supposed to be.

Comment: Does it mean that:

 - You moved hello.jsp in the WEB-INF folder
 - You restarted the Tomcat instance (or re-deployed)
 - You opened http://localhost:8080/springmvcben/hello.html ?

Comment: <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

is it ok?

Comment: Horrific - that won't even deploy. Keep it to *.html, that is not the problem. Please try to reproduce the steps in my previous comment.

Comment: @AlessandroSantini I have tried it before but unfortunately this is not help

Comment: Can you update the screenshost / files you posted with the new situation please?

Comment: Ok I changed it to *.html and it gives HTTP Status 404 error but now I know my controller was worked because I can see my message which ı wrote with System.out.println("some message"); in logs

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /springmvcben/WEB-INF/hello.jsp

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /springmvcben/WEB-INF/hello.jsp

description The requested resource (/springmvcben/WEB-INF/hello.jsp) is not available.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7481/discussion-between-alessandro-santini-and-faridmovsumov)

Comment: That is not the URL you should request - the WEB-INF folder is in fact protected. Try localhost:8080/springmvcben/hello.html and tell me what happens exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I can't duplicate the problem. Things to check:

- That red logging output--what does it say?
- Turn log levels up to DEBUG and re-start Tomcat--any exceptions?
- Make sure you have all the libraries you need.
- Make sure there's a JSTL implementation in your $TOMCAT_HOME/lib directory.

For the last, you can use the [JSTL 1.2 downloads from Glassfish](http://jstl.java.net/download.html). Tomcat/Spring won't start up if those libraries aren't present in Tomcat's `lib` directory because of the Spring configuration.

FWIW, I'm using Maven, and define a single Spring dependency (and Log4J):

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This creates the following dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
```

You need to make sure you have all of those jars *deployed* (not just on the build path).

Comment: I will do what you say step by step..
I have adde log messages to question.
I have added jstl-impl-1.2.jar to tomcat's lib directory.

Comment: @faridmovsumov I can't really read the log, next time use the code formatting and don't break the lines. I don't see any exceptions, however.

Comment: I have changed log how is it now I can't do better sorry:(

Comment: I added jars only under WEB-INF/lib is it mistake?

Comment: @faridmovsumov I also don't see the aopalliance jar, but it may not be strictly necessary. Personally, I'd use Maven--[here's the POM for my working sample](https://github.com/davelnewton/so/blob/master/spring/so9196292/pom.xml).

Comment: @faridmovsumov That's where the jars should go, under the app's `WEB-INF/lib`, assuming they're actually being deployed. Not sure what else to tell you--it works fine for me, modulo that I'm using automatic dependency management. I'd try adding the aopalliance jar, it's included in the full Spring download.

Comment: I have aopalliance-1.0.jar under lib.

Comment: @faridmovsumov Seems like it should be working then; I'd try DEBUG logging and see if anything obvious shows up. The link to that pom file is the root of my working version; I believe I cut-and-pasted everything (except the welcome page, I just open "hello.html" manually).

Comment: ok I will check it. I think I have error here  <context:component-scan base-package="controller" /> because my controller is never visited. When I write system.out.println("some message"); here I can't see anything in logs